# Use of COUNT(DISTINCT myfield)

Tags: sql, vistadb

I am puzzled by a SELECT query I am trying to make. Basically my file has one or more records per invoice, showing its region. I want to find how many invoices each region has.

Here is an example of my table *Table1*

```
InvNo   Region
A1      1
A2      3
A3      2
A4      1
A5      1
A6      2
```

Running the following SQL code gives me what I want BUT includes one extra record I am not expecting - and do not want, apparently for a blank region. I cannot see why this row arises.

```
SELECT Region, COUNT(DISTINCT Invno) as count
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Region
```

Here is the output

```
Region  count
        0       ' I do not want this row!
1       3
2       2
3       1
```

Should I rephrase the code? Or could this be a problem with the SQL platform I am using (VistaDB)?

**UPDATE** The code works fine if I do not call my new column `count` but `myCount` i.e. this works `COUNT(DISTINCT Invno) as myCount`. This reminds me that one should always be careful about the name one gives to variables etc.

Comment: Follow advice below to solve your problem.  You said, "one record per invoice".  Because of this, you should be able to remove the DISTINCT InvNo and just use InvNo, or even better Count(*) for better performance.

Comment: Thanks @G Mastros, you are absolutely right. This is my mistake, as I actually have more than one record per invoice number. Sorry, I will edit my question

Comment: The answers here are good but turned out to be workarounds - the column name issue mentioned in the "update" is the real answer and that is insightful. I think you should add it as the actual accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT Region, COUNT(DISTINCT Invno) as count
FROM table1
GROUP BY Region
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Invno) > 0
```

Comment: For performance reasons, it's better to remove the unwanted data in the where clause instead of the having clause.  (the way @GordonLinoff shows).

Comment: @GMastros, i agree, i'm not familiar with VistaDB and was not sure if it stores them as null or blanks

Comment: If you think you're getting a bad result, be sure to forward it to our team at support.gibraltarsoftware.com - we're all over any case where VistaDB produces an incorrect (generally defined as "not what SQL Server would do")

Answer (score 0):

You have a row where `region` and `inv_no` are both `NULL` (at least `inv_no` is).  You can just filter it out:

```
SELECT Region, COUNT(DISTINCT Invno) as count
FROM table1
WHERE Invno is not null
GROUP BY Region;
```

Comment: This code gives the same problem. I have only these 6 records, no fields are NULL.

Comment: @finch . . . In most databases (and the ANSI standard), the *only* way for `count(distinct)` to return `0` in a `group by` query is for the argument to be `NULL`.  Perhaps Vistadb has some non-standard extension that would cause this behavior in another situation.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

I tried it with InvNo and null region, and null InvNo, both null, and even with a region = 0. The count never returns zero, so I'd say it is a feature with vistadb. But I tested on MySQL, not vistadb.